# Titanium Module (Android) - "Requested module not found"

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I'm creating a module and adding it to an application

application structure:
[image]

module structure:

[image]

access code module:

```
var module = require('ar.com.module');
    $.label.text = module.example();
```

error:

[image]

steps to run application:

1. include module in app
2. clean and build app
3. run to device

   - Titanium SDK version: 3.2.0.GA
   - NDK Android: r8
   - Android plataform (module): android-10

solution to this problem?

Comment: You should not add your answer with the question itself, if you got the answer. You can add it as your own answer. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Add the solution as your own answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

to run the module in a device must be configured deploy-type = "test" in tiapp.xml and install [gperf](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gperf.htm) add to Path.